# SSIS BIML: How to ignore/skip a BIML script while compiling

Tags: ssis-2012, biml

I have set of BIML scripts in my project and one of the package is giving compile error because it has references to some tables which will be replaced by new tables later. This package is independent and is running as scheduled job weekly. I have disabled the schedule job for now and enable after chaning this package.

Now, until the schema changes are done, I still want to compile other scripts which is now not possible unless I remove script from the project. Is there a way to ignore this script during compilation for time being?

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about the problem? I don't think we have enough information here to make a workable reproduction of your issue

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what approach you want to take.

Every object in Biml that represents a component or package in SSIS can be disabled via the attribute Disabled="true" remembering here that booleans are case sensitive so "True" wont be recognised as "true". The good thing with this approach is that you can programmatically switch on or off your assets before compiling using a BimlScript such as

```
Disabled="<#=disableSwitch#>"
```

Secondly, you can use another technique called an includes directive. This means taking the definition of your package/component placing it in a separate Biml file and then programatically including this in the build based on a switch similar to above.

```
<# if(useDefinition == 1){ #>
    <#@ include file="C:\Code\PackageTemplate.Biml" #>
<# } #>
```

Hope this helps.